# Laravel 4.2 : add soft deleted items to whereHas condition

Tags: laravel-4

I have an issue on Laravel 4.2 and found no solution on my Google friend :
I want to get all soft deleted items in a whereHas condition and it doesn't work at all...

Here is the code :

```
$res = $this->model->whereHas('dsps', function ($q) use ($dsp_id) {
                $q->where('dsps.id', $dsp_id);
                $q->withTrashed();
})->get();
```

And I get the following SQL request :

```
select * from `bdc` where (select count(*) from `dsps` inner join `bdc_dsp` on `dsps`.`id` = `bdc_dsp`.`dsp_id` where `bdc_dsp`.`bdc_id` = `bdc`.`id` and `dsps`.`id` = 81 and `dsps`.`deleted_at` is null) >= 1;
```

The problem is clearly that the "deleted_at is null" remains. It should disappear by using the withTrashed() method.

I tried to put the withTrashed() like that :

```
$q->where('dsps.id', $sst_dsp)->withTrashed();
```

and it doesn't changes anything.

How could make that "deleted_at is null" condition from my whereHas request with an elegant solution ?
Thank by advance for your advices !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One solution to this is creating an alternate form of the relationship that includes trashed records.

```
public function dspsTrashed() {
  return $this->hasWhatever()->withTrashed();
}
```

Then:

```
$this->model->whereHas('dspsTrashed', ...);
```

Comment: @ArthurLORENT You're most welcome! You can add all sorts of Eloquent calls to your relationships like this, it can be very handy for making relationships that only return certain rows based on criteria too.